# Bookshelf.js withRelated TypeScript error

Tags: node.js, typescript, orm, knex.js, bookshelf.js

So, in my app I have **categories** and **articles** that are interrelated. At first I retrieve all of **categories** and there are **articles** inside each of them. The problem is I wanna filter both **categories** and **articles** inside it by `userId` but I don't know how to do it since I'm using TypeScript and getting error.

```
const articlesInCategories = (await (await ArticleCategory.fetchAll())
    .query((qb: QueryBuilder) => {
        qb.innerJoin(Table.ARTICLE_CATEGORY_RELATION, 'article_category_relation.category_id', 'article_category.id' );
        qb.innerJoin(Table.ARTICLE, 'article.id', 'article_category_relation.article_id');

        // Next condition is only for Categories not for Articles inside it
        if (roleId == Role.manager) {
            qb.where('user_id', userId);
        }

        qb.orderBy('id', 'desc');
      })
      .fetch({
          withRelated: [{'articles': function (qb: QueryBuilder) => qb.where('user_id', userId)}]
      }));
```

If `userId` for example would be `1`, wanna get only those **categories** which contain **articles** written by user with id `1`. MOREOVER, not all **articles**, but ONLY written by user with id `1`.

I have TS error near `withRelated`: `Type '{ articles: (qb: QueryBuilder) => QueryBuilder<any, any[]>; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)`

Can you help me please with TypeScript in such case or suggest any alternative ways to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that was the wrong approach. If I do the following, it works brilliant:

```
const articlesInCategories = await new ArticleCategory().query((qb: QueryBuilder) => {
    .query((qb: QueryBuilder) => {
        qb.innerJoin(Table.ARTICLE_CATEGORY_RELATION, 'article_category_relation.category_id', 'article_category.id' );
        qb.innerJoin(Table.ARTICLE, 'article.id', 'article_category_relation.article_id');

        if (roleId == Role.manager) {
            qb.where('user_id', userId);
        }

        qb.orderBy('id', 'desc');
      })
      .fetch({
          withRelated: [{ 'articles': (qb: QueryBuilder) => qb.where('user_id', userId) }]
      }));
```